# Quelle typographie adopter concernant les ponctuations et parenthèses

Tags: ponctuation, typographie

Souvent je me retrouve à utiliser des parenthèses pour ajouter une idée à une phrase. Quelle typographie est la meilleure en fonction de la ponctuation ?

```
(.); -- Point dans les parenthèses, suivi de la ponctuation de la principale
```

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de ce fichier (Ne pas le prêter, ne pas le laisser accessible sur un ordinateur, etc.);

```
;(.) -- Point dans les parenthèses après la ponctuation de la principale
```

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de ce fichier; (Ne pas le prêter, ne pas le laisser accessible sur un ordinateur, etc.)

```
(); -- Pas de point dans les parenthèses, suivi de la ponctuation de la principale.
```

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de ce fichier (Ne pas le prêter, ne pas le laisser accessible sur un ordinateur, etc);

Est-ce que cela change en fonction de la ponctuation (Le cas avec un `.` fait particulièrement mauvaise impression `blah (blah.).`)? Est-ce que je devrais éviter ces constructions ?

Comment: Il me semble qu'on met plutôt des points de suspension qu'un point simple après 'etc' en français, non ? C'est à dire qu'on écrit liste de choses, etc...

Comment: @jv42: mettre des points de suspension après 'etc.' est une faute de français courante à éviter (il y a redondance).

Comment: @Dave: pas que je mette en doute, mais serait il possible d'avoir une source officielle ? Ceci m'intrigue - y a t'il eu un changement "récent" ou est-ce la norme depuis toujours ?

Comment: @jv42: [pas de problème](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=etc+points+de+suspension): "Attention ! On écrira au choix : `blablabla etc.` [ou] `blablabla...` mais surtout pas : `blablabla etc…`" ;-)

Comment: @jv42 : Le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie Nationale* indique p. 147 : « On ne doit jamais faire suivre « etc. » de points de suspension. »

Comment: @Raphink: ok c'est noté merci :)

Comment: [Sans smileys, c'est encore facile…](http://xkcd.com/541/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Une remarque avant de répondre : dans tes exemples, le point dans la parenthèse est ambigu, car l'abréviation etc. prend un point même en milieu de phrase.

La ponctuation des parenthèses dépend essentiellement du contenu de la parenthèse.

Si le texte contenu dans la parenthèse termine la phrase courante, alors la ponctuation est placée après la parenthèse :

> Il rentra chez lui (et ça n'était pas bien loin).

Dans ce cas précis, qui est plutôt une incise, j'aurais tendance à utiliser un tiret cadratin:

> Il rentra chez lui — et ça n'était pas bien loin.

Si le texte contenu dans la parenthèse représente une phrase entière, on peut placer la ponctuation dans la parenthèse (et on aura alors une majuscule en début de parenthèse) :

> Ce tableau est visible au musée du Louvre. (Le musée en a fait l'acquisition il y a 150 ans à l'occasion d'une vente privée.)

La ponctuation de la phrase principale se place alors avant la parenthèse.

Je n'aime personnellement pas vraiment les phrase longues et/ou entières dans les parenthèses, et je lui préfère l'usage des notes de bas de page:

> Ce tableau est visible au musée du Louvre<sup>1</sup>. C'est à cette époque que blah blah blah blah blah...
>
> Blah blah blah.
>
> 1. Le musée en a fait l'acquisition il y a 150 ans à l'occasion d'une vente privée.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec l'usage des notes de bas de page. Je ne sais plus qui disait à peu près : « À quoi servent vraiment les parenthèses ? Si c'est pour ajouter quelque chose au texte, pourquoi le mettre en parenthèse ? Si c'est parce que ça n'a que peu de rapport ou d'intérêt, pour l'y laisser ? » Bref, dans un texte écrit, j'utilise très peu les parenthèses (mais ce n'est que mon avis :-) )

Comment: J'utilise les parenthèses pour les références (par exemple les références bibliques) ou les remarques courtes, mais en général, je leur préfère les incises ou les notes de bas de page.

Comment: J'avais appris en cours de français que les parenthèses ne devaient être utilisée que quand le support ne permet pas d'utiliser les notes de bas de page.

Comment: @Evpok: si j'utilisais des notes de bas de page pour chaque référence biblique dans mes textes, ça ressemblerait plus à une édition critique qu'à un simple livre, et ça rendrait le texte plus difficile à lire. Je pense que ça dépend du contexte.

Comment: @Raphink Je pense aussi, ce n'était qu'un avis de prof de français après tout. Mais j'essaie quand même au maximum

Comment: Très bonne réponse. J'ai souvent tendance à mettre des remarques entre parenthèses, et assez souvent, quand je me relis, je supprime ces parenthèses. Je perd un peu d'expressivité (la nuance d'aparté), mais je gagne en clarté, je pense.

Answer (score 7):

En français, on utilise la ponctuation naturellement dictée par la sémantique. Une remarque entre parenthèses à l'intérieur d'une phrase ne constitue pas une phrase complète ; elle ne commence donc pas par une majuscule et ne prend pas de point final.

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de ce fichier (**n**e pas le prêter, ne pas le laisser accessible sur un ordinateur, et ainsi de suite) ; ceci explique qu'elle ne soit vérifiée que dans 5 % des cas observés.

Il peut néanmoins y avoir un point avant une parenthèse fermante s'il indique une abréviation.

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de ce fichier (ne pas le prêter, ne pas le laisser accessible sur un ordinateur, etc.) ; ceci explique qu'elle ne soit vérifiée que dans 5 % des cas observés.

Si une phrase entière est mise entre parenthèses, elle commence par une majuscule et se termine par un point. Il faut, comme pour toute autre phrase, terminer d'abord la phrase précédente par une ponctuation de fin de phrase (point, point d'interrogation, point d'exclamation ou points de suspension).

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de ce fichier. (Gestion rigoureuse signifie ne pas le prêter, ne pas le laisser accessible sur un ordinateur, et ainsi de suite.) Ceci explique qu'elle ne soit vérifiée que dans 5 % des cas observés.

Il peut y avoir un point d'interrogation ou un point d'exclamation avant la parenthèse fermante, pour colorer la phrase entre parenthèses.

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de ce fichier (notamment ne pas le stocker en clair !) ; ceci explique qu'elle ne soit vérifiée que dans 5 % des cas observés.

À noter que les mêmes règles s'appliquent en général aux guillemets, avec quelques particularités. D'abord, une phrase commence toujours par une lettre capitale même si la citation toute seule n'en prendrait pas (cela n'arrive pas avec les parenthèses car une phrase ne commence pas en principe par une parenthèse).

> « Six à huit semaines », répondait-il à chaque fois qu'on lui demandait combien de temps il faudrait.

Ensuite, si l'on cite une phrase complète en fin de phrase, on inclut le point à l'intérieur des guillemets et on omet alors le point final de la phrase englobante.

> Il dit que cela prendra « six à huit semaines ».
>   Il dit : « Il me faudra six à huit semaines. »

On peut avoir une ponctuation à la fois avant et après le guillemet fermant lorsque la phrase englobante est interrogative ou exclamative.

> Il a osé dire : « Il me faudra six à huit semaines. » !

Comment: Bonne réponse ! À noter que les points d'exclamation et d'interrogation ne terminent pas systématiquement une phrase !, on les voit même parfois suivis d'une virgule (comme dans la phrase présente).

Comment: @subtenante : mouais, autant je veux bien [prendre ces points pour des virgules](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_d%27interrogation), autant la leur adjoindre me semble hautement inesthétique.

Answer (score 4):

Pour compléter [la réponse de Raphink](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/359/quelle-typographie-adopter-concernant-les-ponctuations-et-parentheses/361#361) sur un point particulier : ne pas mettre de phrase complète à l'intérieur d'une autre phrase. Donc, la parenthèse contenant une phrase entière se place après le point de la phrase précédente.

L'exemple cité est mal formé :

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que 
>       d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de 
>       ce fichier ; (Ne pas le prêter, ne pas le laisser 
>       accessible sur un ordinateur, etc.) ici vient le 
>       reste présumé de la phrase.

Ce devrait être :

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que 
>       d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de 
>       ce fichier. (Ne pas le prêter, ne pas le laisser 
>       accessible sur un ordinateur, etc.) Modifier
>       le reste de la phrase pour s'adapter à la coupure.

Ou bien :

> Cette propriété ne peut-être le résultat que 
>       d'une gestion particulièrement rigoureuse de 
>       ce fichier (ne pas le prêter, ne pas le laisser 
>       accessible sur un ordinateur, etc.) ; ici vient le 
>       reste présumé de la phrase.

Si le point intérieur à la parenthèse vient d'une locution de type *etc.*, il n'y a pas de problème à le laisser, car il n'est pas un point de ponctuation.

Ceci est parfaitement légitime :

> J'aime tous les fruits (pommes, cerises, *etc.*).