# Suppression du point en fin phrase et en fin de ligne

Tags: typographie, ponctuation

> "...*Dialogue en cours*
>  -Tu as vu ?
>   - Comme c'est beau !"**.**
>   
> .... *suite du texte*

Est-il vraiment nécessaire d'ajouter le *point final*, alors qu'il y a :

- un retour à la ligne,
- un guillemet,
- et surtout une ponctuation forte avant ce dernier ?

**AJOUT** *: Ponctuation double, point d'ironie*

Est-ce que les caractère spéciaux **⁈ ⁇ ⁉** sont utilisables en littérature francophone ? ou seulement dans les média et les publicités ? De plus ont-ils une signification réellement différente ?

Comment: Il manque quelque chose avant la citation qui expliquerait le point.

Comment: @Knu on peut imaginer un dialogue, ou toute phrase entre guillemets terminant une ligne.

Comment: Ce qui précède a une importance.

Comment: La partie ajoutée contient des questions qui ne sont aucunement liées à ce qui précède. Elles ont leur place dans un post distinct du premier. Je te propose de créer ce post et de demander à Mark de déplacer sa deuxième réponse (par copie et suppression).

Comment: Question liée à celle-ci : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/deux-points-dialogue-et-guillemets. Et dans une moindre mesure (même si une réponse à cette question s'y trouve): http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/359/quelle-typographie-adopter-concernant-les-ponctuations-et-parentheses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il y a trois cas.

#### La citation forme une phrase à elle seule

Ce cas est simple : on met des guillemets autour de la citation, et c'est tout. Il n'y a pas de phrase extérieure qui appellerait un point. L'exemple donné dans la question est dans ce cas.

> Ils s'arrêtèrent pour contempler le spectacle.
>
> « Tu as vu ?
> — Comme c'est beau ! »

#### La citation n'est pas une phrase complète

Dans ce cas, la citation ne se termine pas par un signe de ponctuation, et il n'y a donc pas de ponctuation à l'intérieur des guillemets. Si la citation est en fin de phrase, le guillemet fermant est suivi d'un point ou autre ponctuation de fin de phrase.

> Il qualifia le spectable de « très beau ».

#### La citation est une phrase complète et fait elle-même partie d'une phrase

Dès lors que la citation est une phrase complète, on conserve sa ponctuation finale avant le guillemet fermant. Le guillemet fermant peut aussi être suivi d'un signe de ponctuation si la phrase englobante en appelle une.

> « Comme c'est beau ! », s'exclama-t-il.
>
> A-t-il bien dit « Comme c'est beau ! » ?
>
> Il cita Descartes : « Je pense, donc je suis. », ce qui n'impressionna pas son interlocuteur.

Il y a une exception : lorsque la citation est en fin de phrase et que la phrase englobante se termine par un simple point (et non par un point d'exclamation ou d'interrogation ou des points de suspension), on omet en général le point de la phrase englobante.

> Descartes a dit : « Je pense, donc je suis. »

Comment: Limpide ! La première et la dernière citation m'ont fait comprendre où étaient les nuances recherchées, les autres citations ont leur logique naturelle.

Answer (score 1):

**La règle est formelle, toute phrase doit se terminer par un point.**

Point à la ligne, un point c'est tout.

Ce point peut être `.`, `?`, ou `!`. Au passage il est regrettable que le point d'ironie `؟`, inventé au milieu du XIXème siècle, n'ait pas été adopté, sauf parfois dans le *Canard Enchaîné*. Il aurait évité l'emploi erroné de *sic* ou des émoticônes :  `;)`, `:)`, `:D` et autres.

**Concernant l'ajout** :

Pas plus que les points de suspension, les combinaisons `?!`, `!?`, `!!`, `??` n'ont été interdites ; heureusement, car expriment simultanément deux sentiments.

« Que me racontez-vous donc !? » n'a pas le même sens que : « Que me racontez-vous donc ?! ».

N'est pléonastique que le « etc.... » ; l'abréviation de "*et caetera*", soit « etc. », est suspensive en soi : « etc. » est cependant suivi de deux points lorsqu'il placé à la fin d'une phrase : le premier marque l'abréviation, le second la fin de la phrase.

**Plaidoyer pour la licence poétique** :

Le poète est par définition un créateur, et heureusement il peut et même doit ne pas respecter les règles. Il ne faut pas être pointilleux, académique, en art : c'est n'y rien comprendre ou vouloir le tuer.

**Critique que j'attendais, mais qui n'a pas été exprimée** :

Contre les prescriptions, je mets toujours un blanc devant `:` et `;`.
Je trouve le texte bien plus lisible ainsi. Et souvent aussi devant `?` et `!`.

Comment: Je plaide pour une licence poétique, une licence esthétique, une suppression des redondances, une économies de l'inutile ... P.S. j'ai ajouté les caractères 'double ponctuation' que je viens de découvrir à l'instant

Comment: En France, on met toujours une espace fine insécable devant les ponctuations doubles (à l'intérieur, pour les guillemets). Où as-tu rencontré cet usage de conserver le point de l'abréviation lorsqu'un point de fin de phrase suit ? [Ce n'est la règle ni en France ni au Québec](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/abreviations-et-ponctuation-en-fin-de-phrase).